# Visualforce saving PDF fails because of PageReference and getContent() in Experience Cloud/Community

Tags: visualforce, community, pdf, experience-cloud, getcontent

I created a Visualforce page quick action on Opportunity object. It has an iframe to another visualforce page (renderAs='pdf'). The Visualforce Page action (parent) has a custom button to download the iframed Visualforce page. It works completely fine in the org.

I wanted to use this solution in Experience Cloud. I am testing this by logging into the community as a user with a Partner Community License.

So far I have managed to put all of this into the community so the action is working, and I am able to see the inner pdf without an issue.

The problem happens when I click the custom button to download this pdf. I got the following error:

> The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please refresh
> your page and try again.

And this old-school error page:

[image: Error]
The error happens in the following code and at the last line.

```
PageReference pdfToSave = Page.AngebotPDF;

pdfToSave.getParameters().put('id', opportunity.Id);

BLOB pdfToSaveBLOB = pdfToSave.getContent();
```

As far as I understand the Partner Community Licensed user cannot access this pdf from the community. However, the user can see the preview fine and I enabled the page by checking the Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app checkbox from the Visualforce pages.

I believe the problem occurs because I couldn't provide the correct PageReference for the user to access it and get its content via getContent().

Thank you for your help,
Ozan